# Start App with Same User Account after System Restart winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

**The Main Problem**:
I am working on a multi-user WinForms application(Multi-users and an Admin). All I want to know is how to make the application remember the user's account who has logged in to the app even after the system restart.

**My Try**:
I tried it by saving the user's data on a file and reading the user's details(not password) to log in to the app and when the user logs out the file is deleted. Even the file is encrypted, if some of the data is changed, it will ruin the entire experience of the app. It can be both running at system startup or run manually by the user after system restart.

**Possible Alternatives**:
Is there any built-in approach or generally followed mechanism for the scenario?

Thanks in advance Guys!

Comment: Sorry if I am missing something… however, “auto” logging in of the last user is a questionable idea from the start. What if the last user logged in is NOT the first user to use the system after a reboot or startup?

Comment: The login time in my app takes more than 50s (decr(AES256)+hash check(argon2)). So, the app will ask for a pass-phrase if any button is pressed. Any suggestion is welcome my friend!

Comment: I am not sure why the login time would make a difference. And I am not sure what you mean by … _”the app will ask for a pass-phrase if any button is pressed.”_ … ? … Sorry I am not sure what you mean by this. SO if any button is pressed AT ANY TIME the app will ask for the pass-phrase? Again I am sorry if I am missing something obvious. In addition @Caius Jard ‘s answer looks fairly straight forward and should do what you describe. Would not his answer work for you?

Comment: Then, I may rephrase the question "Login in with same user account after system restart". If Any activity on the app is tried to perform after the restart with the previous user account, the app will ask for a passphrase to confirm it is the same user who used before restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open the login form
- Click the username box
- Go to the properties grid and scroll it up to the top
- Find the `(Application settings)` line and expand it to reveal `(Property Binding)`
- Click the 3 dots and find Text in the list that popped up
- Drop it down to reveal a `New..` option
- give it some name like `DefaultUserName` and ensure it is `User` scoped
- ok/ok out of those so you're back at the form
- Click on the form so it is selected
- Switch the property grid to Events (lightning bolt) view
- Double click FormClosing event
- Write code `Properties.Settings.Default.Save()`

This stores the last user login name only, for the currently logged on windows user.. like a "remember me" box on the web. It doesn't keep a history of everything ever typed into the username box, and it doesn't remember settings across different windows user logins (both those things would be a security issue, really) - it just offers a nice convenience of repeat users not having to type their same username in again and again

Comment: Your approach is good, But it is not what I asked for, it just fills up the textbox with username and password waiting for the user to click the login button. is there any method like directly getting into the main application without logging in by just getting a passphrase, But maintaining the memory of user logged in before system restart. 

Like
`
if(user loggedin == true)
{
save username for checking after restart
}
else if(user loggedout == true)
{
delete saved username for checking after restart.
}
//After Restart
if(username found == true)
{
ask for passphrase only 
}
`

Comment: I can't make sense of the request.You said "I just want to ask the user for a password and not have to put a username but your approach pre-fills the username box and means they only have to fill in their password" - er.. yes.. that implements what you requested, and it still shows the user a username so they can change it if they want(like if one human has two accounts). If the user is logged out, you can do `Properties.Default.DefaultUserName = ""` before you save to clear the saved username next time. Or just let the user change the displayed username if they want to log in as someone else

Comment: I think you understood the scenario in a different way, let me put like this,
1. User signin 
2. User restarts the system without logging out(so the app should save the user's credentials in some place)
3. After Restart, The user launches the app and the app shows the same user's account(who logged in before sys-restart) without logging in but, If the user does any activity on app, it asks for a passphrase.
4. The user logs out and the memory for the user to store after sys.restart is erased.(starts as a fresh app with login screen after system restart)

Comment: Definitely an odd requirement, but you can use the same system as described above still, as all it is is a settings system that saves data between restarts. At quit time, If they're logged in, Save an encrypted string of where the user was when they quit and upon restart decrypt the string if there is one, and send them back to a view of where they were but not logged in so that whenever they click anything they're prompted for login. That's the hardest part; implementing a full permissions system on everything they can do- well out of the scope of a comment on an SO answer

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, But that's what already tried. but if anything on encrypted text is changed by a user by mistake. Then the experience of the app is ruined. So, I liked your "Remember Me" Part. How to remove the "Save State" if the user unchecks the remember me checkbox. I can remove this previous part. Thank you.